# Photon emission/absorption by an atom and local gauge invariance

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, gauge-invariance, photon-emission

I understand that the local gauge invariance leads to a photon emission/absorption when the phase of an electron field is changed while the amplitude being unchanged.

I'd like to know whether this is true for the case of a photon emission/absorption by an atom, for example, in the Lyman alpha transition 2p-1s in hydrogen. If not, is there any alternative principle for this kind of photon emission/absorption other then the gauge principle?

Comment: I find this question very unclear. What do you mean by the "amplitude of the wave function" being changed? What kind of explanation "in terms of local gauge invariance" do you want other than that the photon is the quantum of the gauge field? Why do you think this process can be described with a Feynman diagram? (Note that bound states are not available as in/out states for a diagram, since the in/out states are the states of a *free* theory)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've modified my question to make the point clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the  Schrodinger equation for the Hydrogen atom (and the Dirac equation yields the same [solutions](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html))  is very successful in giving the Lyman series. It is a postulate that the difference in the energy levels leaves as a real photon, and gives the observed spectra. This is first quantization.

When one talks of gauge invariance  leading to emission absorption from electrons one is in the realm of second quantization, field theory.

> [QED is our first complete example](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node508.html) of an interacting Quantum Field Theory.
>
> ....
>
> We have written the fields of the photon and the electron in terms of creation and annihilation operators.

[This lecture](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Emsafrono/626/Lecture%202-3.pdf) explores the Feynman diagrams needed to treat the electron of the hydrogen atom in QED.

In [PDF page 24 of this book](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/%7Ekleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-11-qed.pdf) it is clear that in the hydrogen atom photons are emitted because of creation and annihilation operators  having a large probability for transition. So for the hydrogen atom your  statement "the local gauge invariance leads to a photon emission/absorption" is irrelevant. Actually you do not give a link so I cannot think how relevant it is even for Compton scattering ( absorption and emission of a photon  ) page 33 and on in the same link.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What happens to the field of a bound electron when it emits/absorb a photon in transition? Is it a change in phase and/or amplitude?

Comment: the wavefunction changes when an electron changes energy levels, this means both the phase and the amplitude will be different.

Comment: Is the phase change here related to the one told in the local gauge invariance? Or are they completely different concepts?

Comment: I has to be consistent with it, is is not really a prediction, it is a whole mathematical frame hanging together consistently. The statement you quote ( no link) "local gauge invariance leads to a photon emission/absorption when the phase of an electron field is changed while the amplitude being unchanged." makes the emmision consistent, but cause is a moot point. Is momentum conservation a cause or a constraint in two body decays?

Comment: My statement may be wrong since it is based on my understanding of what is written in "Symmetry and the beautiful universe" by Leon Lederman. Since I read the book translated into other language, my English expression also may not be good. The relevant figure is Fig.25, which can be seen in "Look inside" at Amazon. I understand that the figure is saying that if you apply gauge transformation (, which I understand is a phase transformation,) to an electron, the momentum of the electron changes, but a photon is emitted so that the the momentum change is compensated, which is gauge invariance.

Comment: Seems to me it is a description on where one can see the effects of gauge invariance. Similar to in a two body decay if you measure the energy of one particle  energy conservation gives you the energy of the other. The "apply gauge transofrmation here" is like "apply energy conservation here" . One cannot talk of cause and effect. It is a collective consistency of the theoretical model that describes the measurements, same as all conservation laws which also come from symmetries.